# Creating custom Web application to List EJBs Deployed on WebLogic 10.3.X

Tags: runtime, jmx, weblogic-10.x, mbeans

I need to create a seperate application which can list all the EJBs deployed on Weblogic along with all the attributes displayed on deployment page for that EJB.

I want a pointer to get the reference to `MessageDrivenEJBRuntimeMBean` with which I  can get other details.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some code? Have you looked at an example with WLST like http://middlewaresnippets.blogspot.com/2011/10/using-wlst-to-obtain-weblogic-runtime.html ? The same type of calls should translate to java JMX.

Comment: I Have tried the code samples from http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/jmx/accessWLS.html link and ran them successfully Earlier I had seen the link about wlst scripts but can we run those from a java web app?